# Changing iOS VoiceOver settings programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, voiceover, uiaccessibility

I'm developing an app for visually impaired users and they would like to change VoiceOver settings directly from the app because using the rotor to do so is cumbersome. Is there any way to change ex. VoiceOver speed via code from the app?

Comment: No. Apple does not allow developers to change these settings.